# Only time picker with rails simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have implemented the jquery datatime picker with simple_form.
Have implemented the gem 'jquery-rails' for date with time format.

Is there any way, where I can get only time piker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another jquery plugin [TimePicki](https://github.com/senthilraj/TimePicki) or [jquery-timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

[image]